# Simultaneous video recording, frame preview and raw frames access

Tags: android, performance, camera

We need to run simultaneously:

- video recording (prefer FHD)
- frame preview
- run some statistics on frame.

We tried few approaches:

1. using Camera.PreviewCallback - works fine while no video recording, frames stop to arrive on most devices when recording is active (for example Nexus 5)
2. TextureView - works on all devices that we tried, but getBitmap takes time, so it blocks ui thread and user sees not smooth preview behaviour

What is correct way to get

- video recording
- frame preview
- run some statistics on frame.

Thanks you in advance,

Svetlana

Comment: My guess is that you will need to stop using video recording and build your own video from the `PreviewCallback` frames, the way Vine did.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it will be possible to record FHD this way ?

Comment: Why do TextureView callbacks block UI thread? You should open the camera in a separate event thread, so that the processing does not interfere with the main thread. Also, you probably need to offload image processing into another worker thread, to keep camera output unblocked.

Comment: "Do you think it will be possible to record FHD this way ?" -- only if you have FHD preview frames.